# How do I "recompile" html that was pushed using mustachejs in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have some html code that gets rendered through Mustache JS. This html code uses angular directive (ng-click) but since the html is injected on an event, angular is not aware of the ng-click and doesn't work. How do I recompile the html so angular is aware of the directive after new html is injected?

Edit:
This renderer method is called when a graph node is clicked. A tooltip is suppose to appear but I just want a button. I am using sigmaJS for my graph library. [SigmaJS tooltip](https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/tree/develop/plugins/sigma.plugins.tooltips)

```
renderer: function(node, template) {
              // Returns an HTML string:
              var template = "<button ng-click=\"test\">someButton</button>"

              return Mustache.render(template, node);
            }
```

Comment: Added with an edit

Comment: I'm not sure if creating a sigma directive will help. The HTML for the tooltip will still need to be injected during a mouse event.